# How to locally resolve host name starting with variable slug?

Tags: docker, dns

An app, running on my laptop in development mode, comprises several Docker containers, one of which runs a Django web app.

This web app expects to receive HTTP requests using a hostname with a variable leading part, e.g. "test-account.survey.com", in which 'test-account' is a slug representing a particular account, and the remaining string 'survey.com' is fixed.

Now I know this can be resolved in a Live environment, involving external HTTP requests, by using wildcard DNS servers [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record ].

But I'd like to set up and configure on my laptop a local DNS server for the sole purpose of forwarding hostnames as above to a fixed IP address, e.g. 127.0.0.1 and "passing through" any other hostnames.

Any recommendations? Thanks in anticipation.

P.S. The DNS server must support Windows 10 and Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

People often use dnsmasq for this.  You can wildcard sub-domains like this fairly easily for local testing using it.

Here's an example - https://qiita.com/bmj0114/items/9c24d863bcab1a634503 but there are plenty online.